# In U-Prove, what is the purpose of "Pseudonyms", "Committed", and "Scope" values and how are they used?

Tags: cryptography, authentication, protocols, authorization, u-prove

[U-Prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-Prove) allows for anonymous authentication and authorization without the involvement of an [IdP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider).

When a client generates a presentation proof 3 values can be optionally included, but I can't find intuitive documentation on how or why to use them.  The values are:

- Pseudonyms
- Commitments
- Scope

I examined the sourcecode and infer that the `pseudonym` is used by a hardware device, and not sure if this usage is exclusive to the prover's device, or if the usage can be expanded to more creative scenarios.  I simply don't understand the value this provides.

I suspect `scope` is a string generated by the verifier (a.k.a. authorization target), but am unclear on how frequently it must be updated (per token or presentation) or what it should contain.

The `commitments` attribute is very interesting since part of the source code says it's for protocol extensions, but I haven't seen any extensions take advantage of this, let alone understand how or why the protocol can be expanded.  It does seem to be related to `FieldZqElements` and the `tildeO` variables.

This is what I found in the source code describing these variables:

> ***`committed`**: An ordered array of committed attribute indices.*
>   ***`pseudonymAttribIndex`***: Index of the attribute used to create a scope-exclusive pseudonym, or 0 if no pseudonym is to be presented.
>   The index must not be part of the disclosed attributes.
>   ***`gs`***: The pseudonym scope element, or null if no pseudonym is to be presented.

Can anyone elaborate on these 3 (and any other related variable), and how they would be used in a to-be-invented security protocol?  (e-voting, limited use, x "greater than" y, etc)

Comment: In [this Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/u-prove/) you can find the email addresses of the developers. Did you try asking them? Also, is this question still useful / applicable after 6 years?